# Запись бинарных данных в xml при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, xml

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Пытаюсь записать бинарные данные в xml файл такого типа:

```
    <node0>val0</node0>
    <node1>val1</node1>
    <node2>val2</node2>
    <node3>....</node3> - тут должны находиться бинарные данные
```

А в итоге в node3 пишется 'NaN'. Вот кусок кода, отвечающий за запись:

```
    xml+='<node0>val0</node0>';
    xml+='<node1>val1</node1>';
    xml+='<node2>val2</node2>';
    xml+='<node3>';
    variable = new ArrayBuffer(4); 
    variable[0] = 33;
    variable[1] = 36;
    variable[2] = 33;
    variable[3] = 36;
    xml+= variable[0] + variable[1] + variable[2] + variable[3];
    xml+='</node3>';
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы в текстовом документе были прямо вот бинарные данные? Там же могут быть нечитаемые символы например. Ещё у вас variable[4] выходит за границу вашего буфера.

Comment: variable[4] точно, не заметил, спасибо. А по-поводу вопроса, да, я хочу чтобы в текстовом документе были бинарные данные, возможно ли это?

Comment: Обычная практика - кодировать бинарные данные или в `hex` или `base64`, и полученную строку уже вставлять как текст. Хотя в принципе конечно можно и бинарные данные вставлять.

Comment: А вы не могли бы скинуть ссылку на описание, или пример?

Comment: На вскидку от гугла: https://chawi3.com/2015/03/03/arraybuffer-to-base64-base64-to-arraybuffer-javascript/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Прямо скажем, я не вижу тут XML. Пока что у вас просто строка. По стандарту XML в нём не должно быть бинарных данных. Впрочем ваш код туда всё равно запишет одно число в строковом виде.

Comment: блин, правда не все данные преобразовались в hex, а в чем проблема не подскажете?

Comment: Так вы приведите требования, предъявляемые к этому "XML", не до конца понятно что вам нужно в итоге получить.

Comment: вообщем я хочу чтобы строка выглядела следующим образом:

<node3>;8</node3> - Это число 15160(3B38)

Comment: А число 0 или 1 у вас как должно выглядеть?